# После сокрытия элемента методом .hide() метод .toggle() перестает работать

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle

Повесил обработчик клика на кнопку отображающую, скрывающую дополнительный блок со списком. Все работает.

```
$('.button').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var ul = $(this).next('.ul');
  ul.toggle();
});
```

Решил сделать еще так, что бы дополнительный блок скрывался при клике за его пределами.

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    var ul = $('.ul');
    if (!ul.is(event.target) && ul.has(event.target).length === 0 && ul.is(':visible')) {
        ul.hide();
    }
});
```

После этого `toggle` перестал работать. Уже перепробовал разные комбинации кода со всевозможных сайтов, но ничего не помогает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка.

Comment: Пример на https://jsfiddle.net/Evginiy/ttfx8qLz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш обработчик `click` на документе выполняется и в случае нажатия кнопки. Чтобы это предотвратить, используйте `event.stopPropagation`.

```
$('.button').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation(); // !!!
  var ul = $(this).next('.ul');
  ul.toggle();
});
```

*Пояснение*

Сначала выполняется обработчик клика на кнопке. Он делает `.ul` видимым. Потом (если нет `event.stopPropagation`) выполняется обработчик клика на документе. В этот момент `.ul` - видимый, а `event.target` (кнопка) находится вне `.ul`. И `.ul` снова прячется.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Только не понятно, ведь обработчик поднявшись до document не должен проваливаться в условие if и закрывать блок.

Comment: @Евгений В обработчике для документа Вы не проверяете `event.target` на `.button`.

Comment: Igor наверно я что-то не правильно понимаю. Я думал что hide в document сработает только при полном соответствии условию if. А условие вроде гласит: клик не должен быть на блоке И не должен быть на его потомках И блок должен быть развернут. Или hide может сработать  без учета условия?

Comment: @Евгений мне кажется при клике на кнопку и видимом `.ul` все условия удовлетворяются. Сейчас посмотрю фидл.

Comment: @Евгений Да. Сначала выполняется обработчик клика на кнопке. Он делает `.ul` видимым. Потом (если нет `event.stopPropagation`) выполняется обработчик клика на документе. В этот момент `.ul` - видимый, а `event.target` (кнопка) находится вне `.ul`.

Comment: Igor спасибо большое за разъяснение! Нужно хорошо знать логику JS чтобы понять происходящие и не всегда очевидные процессы.

Comment: @Евгений Не за что. Успехов в программировании!